# Is there any alternative mechanism of using 7 relays?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design

I want to control 7 AC bulbs using a microcontroller. Only one bulb will be ON at a time. I can do that using 7 relays. But Is there any alternative mechanism or IC that can do that with low cost, less wiring and with saving space?

Remember, I don't need more than one light being turned on, but with relays, any number of lights can be turned on and off; so relays are kind of a waste here.

[image: controlling 4 bulbs using 4 relays and microcontroller; how to replace relays to do that]

Optocouplers and TRIAC can be used but it will not be low cost or less wiring than relays.

PS: I'm not a graduate of Electronics Engineering (I'm a Computer Science graduate). I thought it will be helpful to know when you're answering.

Comment: Using DC LEDs , will be much cheaper with a shift register and driver.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yeah controlling dc circuit is much easier and cheaper using microcontroller. Controlling AC with microcontroller sometimes becomes a huge pain.

Comment: You can also use DC in AC bulbs but there is a surge current 10x same as AC

Comment: Are we talking about *AC mains* power?  How does your insurance company feel about this?  Are you in a country with an electrical code?  If AC mains, is there any way you can settle for low voltage DC?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine yes this circuit will be used with mains electricity. Working with mains electricity is not considered as a crime in my country (yet). But always precautions has to be taken while working with high voltage AC.

Comment: Don't use extremist language like that. Just because it isn't a CRIME doesn't mean it's OK to ignore the standardized safety codes which keep people safe.  There's a right way to do it. Do it right, don't "freestyle" your own private version of safety codes based on nothing.  OR..... do this project in low voltage, easy mode.

Comment: Speaking about manner of answer, we should talk about manner of question first. Before asking someone about feeling of insurance company, ask do they have life insurance fist. Otherwise, It is just disturbing. Also try giving some sense to your question with some background before asking it, when you are talking to someone abroad. I don't know why the word "crime" is a problem here when we are talking about legal matters. Somehow did it sound rude!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with 4 two pole change over relays or just 3 if you have a 4 pole changeover relay available.

Relays 3 and 4 are driven together if two pole changeover ones are used. Four pole changeover relays are not as common as two pole is the reason I suggest that.

It is basically a binary selection tree.

Relay one selects between the first and second group of 4 lamps.

Relay 2 selects the first or second pair within each of those groups of lamps.

Relay 3 and 4 (or just relay 3 if you have a four pole relay available) selects the odd or even lamp from each pair.

Lamp 0 is intentionally missing - select that one so no lamp is illuminated. This is the state with no relays energized.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5fQql.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Two pole change over relay! I need more time to understand the connection between each relay and microcontroller. One quick question - if it can turn on/off 4 bulbs, then do I need first two relays (relay 1 and 2)? Can't I just use relay 3 and 4 directly with microcontroller? (-was it a silly question!). 
And are those less or more cost than 7 relays?

Comment: @TareqNewazShahriar You can see how a 3-to-8 decoder looks with relays [here](https://youtu.be/tsp2JntuZ3c?t=986). I just purchased 4PDT Fujitsu fbr442nd012 relays for USD 1.50 each. So they are not expensive. However, I cannot say they would handle your bulbs as I don't have specific details about them.

Comment: @jonk thanks. Sounds like a good idea with electronics -- 3 binary inputs to produce 8 different states. I will check the video out.

Comment: @TareqNewazShahriar Be careful when watching it. If you are a died in the wool programmer type, you may decide to create a computer out of relays as the video author did!

Comment: Would really be best for the at-rest (de-energized/NC) position to be the empty bulb.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine - Agreed that is a nicer arrangement.

Comment: @TareqNewazShahriar - The first two relays can only turn off lamps but at the same turning on others - the first two relays are necessary. There are 8 possible states of the three banks of relays. There are 8 possible states of the lamps (including all off). It cannot be done with fewer relays. Two pole changeover relays are very common, probably more common than single pole changeover.

Comment: @KevinWhite so many things to say. 1. The circuit and the mechanism are clear now. thanks you so much. 2. Two pole changeover relays are a bit costly here in my country. Four times the price of a single pole relay. So I will wait a bit for more cost effective and simpler mechanism. 3. But above all, this circuit opened a whole new window for me to think about circuit design; use of algorithmic complex tricks.

Comment: @jonk ohoo! I was on the verge of making one. If you hadn't say it, I would have complete it. ;)

Comment: @TareqNewazShahriar I considered a bit-serial ALU to cut down on relays. But it will take some serious thought yet if I'm to find an avenue that reduces the relay-count enough to matter. There is an allure of sorts in realizing that the more important and difficult to create new ideas were developed by those leading up to and including Turing and Church and that the rest was just a matter of rolling back down the hill from those intellectual heights.